# why does pthread_exit throw something caught by ellipsis?

Tags: c++, exception, pthreads, cancellation

if the function called by `pthread_create` has the following structure

```
try{
  ...code....
  pthread_detach(pthread_self());
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}catch(...){
  std::cout<<"I am here"<<std::endl;
}
```

why does the exception handler for ellipsis get called at the execution of `pthread_exit`?
(note that `std::exception`, for instance, are not thrown)

Comment: What compiler are you seeing this under?

Comment: @Fabio Maybe some destructor of an object on the stack is throwing.

Comment: @DaveS g++
TorstenRobitzki thank you,I though the same, but the case was the one  explained by eran

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At least in GCC `pthread_exit` might throw an ___forced_unwind exception, that is used for unwinding the stack during the thread exit. It does not inherit from `std::exception`, and therefore cannot be caught as one. If you do catch that exception, be sure to re-`throw` it so it can do its job:

```
try {
...
} catch (abi::___forced_unwind&) {
    throw;
} catch (...) {
    // whatever
}
```

The reason an exception is thrown is that `pthread_exit` is specified never to return. Having it throw guarantees cleanup of stack-allocated variables, and no execution of code after its location (unless you catch the unwind exception...). However this is not portable, and Clang for example uses a completely different mechanism.

BTW, this is yet another case where the `catch (...)` idiom does more harm than good. It is sometimes used to "stabilize" code that is throwing unknown exceptions. But that only defers the visibility of the damage to a later time and place, making it impossible to identify the real origin of the problem. The only reasonable thing to do in such a catch is minimal cleanups, possibly logging, and then rethrowing. A process that crashes due to an unhandled exception is not a pretty sight, but it can provide a debugable crash dump that clearly shows the faulty command. But that's just my grudge against `catch (...)`, which is barely related to `pthread_exit`...

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly the case!
and I guess your throw is for preventing

FATAL: exception not rethrown

thank you!

Comment: @Fabio: The `abi::__forced_unwind exception` can also be thrown in threads that have been canceled with `pthread_cancel`. Be careful with the ellipsis catch when terminating pthreads.

Comment: Very interesting, but I'd be interested to learn more on `__force_unwind` and the 2012 link is broken